# Twilio Autopilot SMS not accepting media image type

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-autopilot

I wrote a task a while back that would run a collect flow and collect an image using the model on the docs for doing so (https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/collect#questions). It ran flawlessly, and I tested it to make sure it ran as expected.
I made a new account using the company email to migrate my work over, and continue implementing the code, and eventually reached the portion where I needed to integrate that media collection. I used the same code, but it didn't work. The collect flow keeps on triggering the validate portion and telling me that it isn't an accepted type. I have tried it using the exact code from before as well as the exact image, but it still isn't working. The only thing I can think of is if the phone number was set up differently somehow. The message logs show the image as sent and looks fine and I can't find any differences other than that. 
Is there anything that might be causing this? Here is the code for reference

```
{
    "actions": [
        {
            "collect": {
                "name": "image_collect",
                "questions": [
                    {
                        "question": "Please upload an image",
                        "name": "image",
                        "type": "Twilio.MEDIA",
                        "validate": {
                            "on_failure": {
                                "messages": [
                                    {
                                        "say": "We do not accept this format. Please send another image."
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "allowed_types": {
                                "list": [
                                    "image/jpeg",
                                    "image/gif",
                                    "image/png",
                                    "image/bmp",
                                    "application/pdf"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "on_complete": {
                    "redirect": "https://4894-100-33-3-193.ngrok.io/image_processing"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that the image is defining it's mime type as `image/jpg` and you're only allowing `image/jpeg`?

Comment: @philnash I just tried the change, and it doesn't fix it. I also looked it up and it looks like iphones default to jpeg so that wasn't the issue. What confuses me the most is that it is the exact same code other than the fact that I had to migrate the code between accounts which shouldn't change anything. Do you know of any phone number setups or permissions I might have to change?

Comment: Are you using a phone number outside of the US and Canada?

Comment: No it is a New York number, so that shouldn't be the issue

Comment: If this is the same code that acts differently across different accounts/numbers, then you should contact [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and provide some message SIDs where this happened.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, media size causes this issue, just make sure the file size is within the limits.

For more info - https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/accepted-mime-types